# Using clock and enable

Tags: vhdl

I was given a code for a D Flip-Flop with enable.

```
process(clk, en)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
             if en = ‘1’ then
                 Q <= D;
        end if;
     end if;
end process;
```

1. I was told that I should **not** use `if rising_edge(clk) and en = ‘1’ then ...`. **Why?**
2. Why isn't the if for the `en = '1'` before the if for clock since the clock is changing more often?
3. And is it necessary to specify that `en` in the process parenthesis `process(clk, en)`?

Comment: Putting `en` before `rising_edge` could infere a gated clock. Ordering signals by changing propabilities or by priority could ease the readability, because many people do it and expect it that way :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Some people believe that the VHDL compilers and synthesizers are not able to figure out that it's the same thing as you've shown here. I've never directly compared the output, but I'd be pretty sad if it mattered.
2. Changing more often doesn't really matter in hardware. In theory, it shouldn't matter. In practice, the compiler will probably incorrectly warn about your sensitivity list if you changed the order of the conditionals.
3. It is not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to all 3 of your questions:

If you're coding sequential logic, it is wise to stick to a template. Here is one such template for sequential logic with *no asynchronous reset*, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
process(clock)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

So `en` should not be in the senstivity list and it should not be tested in the same if statement as the clock is tested.

If you think about it, there is another good reason why `en` should not be in the sensitivity list: the output of a flip-flop with no asyncrhonous reset only changes when the clock changes; it does not change when the D input changes.